# Zend Framework 2: 'ORA-00911: invalid character' when passing string parameter

Tags: oracle, frameworks, zend-framework2, adapter

I'm trying to execute a query with Zend Framework 2 Db Adapter in this way:

```
$db = new Adapter(array(
    'driver'            => 'oci8',
    'username'          => 'myusername',
    'password'          => 'mypassword',
    'connection_string' => 'myconnectionstring',
    'charset'           => 'utf8',
));

$sql       = 'SELECT lastname FROM accounts WHERE username = ?';
$statement = $db->createStatement($sql, array('luca'));
$result    = $statement->execute();
```

But PHP gives me this message:

```
[23-May-2013 10:23:30 Europe/Rome] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught
  exception 'Zend\Db\Adapter\Exception\RuntimeException'
  with message 'ORA-00911: invalid character' in
  /var/www/zend/server/library/ZF2-.2.0/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Driver/Oci8/Statement.php:261

Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/secure/zendAuth2.php(92): 
    Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Oci8\Statement->execute()
#1 {main}
    thrown in /var/www/zend/server/library/ZF2-2.2.0/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Driver/Oci8/Statement.php on line 261
```

The invalid character in the SQL seems to be the '?'. What am I doing wrong? Reading on Framework manual it seems to be correct (http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.db.adapter.html#query-preparation-through-zend-db-adapter-adapter-query) but I still get this error. 
If instead I use

```
$sql       = 'SELECT lastname FROM accounts WHERE username = :username';
$statement = $db->createStatement($sql, array(':username' => 'luca'));
$result    = $statement->execute();
```

it works fine.

Thanks for the help.